# Add VAT to Price

Tags: php, math

I have 2 variables: $vatRate and $priceExVat. I want to create another variable named $endPrice which adds the VAT on. I have no clue on how to do this, and am a begginner at PHP so I would like to have a code example ;)

```
$priceExVat == $_POST['priceExVat'];
$vatRate = $_POST['vatRate'];
rtrim($vatRate ,'%');
$endPrice = ($vatRate * $priceExVat) + $priceExVat;
echo $endPrice;
```

EDIT: Above is the non-working code which returns a 0

Comment: How is $vatRate specified? And is this homework?

Comment: Is rate specified as percentage.

Comment: You aswell :( its already 20%

Comment: I don't think there is enough information in the question for anyone to answer it properly, unless they guess and get it right. Some answers divide by 100, some multiply by 100, some gives sums, some give products... can you write a mathematical formula explaining what you'd like to do?

Comment: You need to find out if VatRate is specified as a percentage or not before we can properly answer. Are you George Osbourne btw ;-)

Comment: You need to remove the double == from the "$priceExVat == $_POST['priceExVat'];" line - you're doing an equality check, not an assignment hence the problems. :-)

Comment: Ahah! Your right @ middaparka

Comment: @DogPooOnYourShoe Your calculation is also completely wrong, but that's another issue. :-)

Comment: @middaparka: OK that needs to be sorted too, but now my values should be right but it doesnt add VAT right :(

Comment: @DogPooOnYourShoe - Look at my answer (amongst others) and see how we carry out the calculation - it should be pretty self evident.

Comment: "Above is the non-working code which returns a 0 " ...you do know that a `return` is not the same as an `echo`, right? If this is in a function, you probably should have `return`, not `echo`.

Comment: can sombody count total of downvote+upvote in comments and answers?

Comment: @ajreal It's like we've slipped into some alternate version of SO where everything we know is wrong. :-)

Comment: @middaparka - wahahaha...it can not be wrong, just that everyone has 30 votes to cast daily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$endPrice = ($vatRate * $priceExVat) + $priceExVat;
```

or

```
$endPrice = (1+$vatRate * $priceExVat);
```

Example

```
$vatRate = 0.07;
$priceExVat = 100.00;
```

Since getting -3

All the answer is somehow wrong if the value is string **20%**

```
$endPrice = ((int)$vatRate/100)*$priceExVat)+$priceExVat;
```

Comment: Not if VatRate is defined in percent.

Comment: @James: OP never really explained if it was, so anyone answering is guessing.

Comment: **for downvoter, this answer appear before OP said is percentage**, take it back

Comment: What is inside $vatRate is ONLY the value "20%"

Comment: @DogPoo: So it is a string literal that is `20%`? In that case you'd have to remove the `%` before you can do any mathematical operations on it. Please edit your question to make it clearer to everyone else wtf is going on.

Comment: I removed the percentage symbol, and posted my non-working code. It still doesnt work and returns a 0

Comment: you have to reassign it back `$vatRate=rtrim($vatRate ,'%');`

Comment: You are also right, however if I enter "100" it will return "2100" as the value with VAT added on. Any more help apart from the == and the = is mixed up?

Comment: **my dear,** if the vat is percentage, you need to divine by 100

Comment: +1 From me, if only because you should never have had a downvote. :-)

Answer (score 7):

To break it down in full:

```
<?php
  $vatRate = 20;        // This must be the percentage VAT rate. e.g.: 20, 17.5.
  $priceExVat = 10;
  $vatComponent = ($priceExVat / 100) * $vatRate;
  $endPrice = $priceExVat + $vatComponent;

  echo 'The resultant price is &pound;' . number_format($endPrice, 2);
?>
```

Incidentally, you may require the VAT portion at a later date, so if you're using this in any non-trivial manner you should really store the base (i.e.: pre-VAT) price and then apply the VAT rate and round accordingly for the purposes of output.

Additionally, you may also want to allow for multiple VAT rates, as not all goods are taxed at 20% in the UK. (Some are exempt, some are taxed at the "reduced" 5% rate, etc.)

Comment: Assuming VatRate is a percentage, yes.

Comment: @James Walford - Good point. (If it was a proper function/method, I'd have said that in the phpdoc param.) :-)

Comment: What is inside $vatRate is ONLY the value "20%"

Comment: @DogPooOnYourShoe This should simply be "20" for my example to work. (You could use rtrim('20%' ,'%') to remove the percentage if so required.)

Comment: Every bit of code I try returns a 0, I will post my code on my question and hopefully someone can fix it for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it should be done:

```
function vat($ex_vat,$vat = 20.0)
{
    return round($ex_vat+ ((double)$vat*($ex_vat/100)),2);
}
```

Example:

```
$withVat = vat(80,20); //£0.80 > £0.96
```

Comment: Good point about the rounding, though if your code actually returned £0.80 > £1.00 I'd have to ask for a refund... ;-)

Comment: Haha, here yo ugo so `£0.04` refund.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $vatRate is specified as percentage.

```
$endPrice = $priceExVat * $vatRate/100
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$vatRate = "20%";
$priceExVat = 100;    
$endPrice = (intval($vatRate) / 100) * $priceExVat + $priceExVat;
```

Comment: Highly unlikey that the variable VatRate is actually Vat amount.

Comment: You dont know that since it's not specified in the question. I assume it's like this till specified otherwise. The var is called rate, not percentage.

Comment: What is inside $vatRate is ONLY the value "20%"